# Problems with password_verfiy when checking a user's password

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a method for checking the password called `checkPassword` and another called `getUser` which checks if they exist and if so, returns a username and password (this is where I believe it is going wrong).

The `checkPassword` method:

```
public function checkPassword($username, $password)
{
   $info = $this->getUser($username);

   if ($info['exists'] == FALSE) {
       exit('The specified user does not exist!');
   }

    if (password_verify($password, $info['password']))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

The `getUser` method:

```
public function getUser($username)
{
    $userInfo = array(
    'username' => $username
    );

    if ( ! $stmt = $this->Connection()->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $this->_info['Prefix'] . "users
    WHERE `".implode("`, `", array_keys($userInfo))."` = ?"))
    {
        echo 'Prepare Failed: ' . $stmt->error . '<br />';
        return FALSE;
    }

    if ( ! $stmt->bind_param('s', $userInfo['username']))
    {
        echo 'Bind Failed: ' . $stmt->error . '<br />';
        return FALSE;
    }

    if ( ! $stmt->execute())
    {
        echo 'Execute Failed: ' . $stmt->error . '<br />';
        return FALSE;
    }

    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($row);

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 0)
        {
            $this->_user['exists'] = FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_user['exists'] = TRUE;
        }

        while ($stmt->fetch())
        {
            $this->_user['username'] = $row['username'];
            $this->_user['password'] = $row['password'];
        }

        $stmt->close();
        return $this->_user;
}
```

To use this I have a separate file called `demo_test.php` to test the functionality. All other methods (Utilising the `getUser` method) all work, the only failure when I try to check the user's password.

This is what I have in `demo_test.php`:

```
    <?php

// Require in file
require_once 'demo.php';

$User = new User('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'test', '8889', NULL);

if ($User->checkPassword('Test', 'Test'))
{
  echo 'Correct Password';
}
else
{
  echo 'Incorrect Password';
}
```

I am being returned with `Incorrect Password` even though the password is correct. The password column length is set to 255.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** (Added Password Hashing Method)

```
private function passwordHash($string)
    {
        $encryption = array(
            'Password' => $string
        );
        $hashed_password = password_hash($encryption['Password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        return $hashed_password;
    }
```

This is how it is stored:

```
1   Matt    $2y$10$36xehsxDeQR6hC6WOO80IuKXb5Fm5fmKCnoB/8xtBPhWDFiKlvh8O
```

Comment: Show the script where you're saving the password for a new user.

Comment: @EvadeCaptcha Do you mean where the user's account is created? Or the password hashing method?

Comment: Probably more the password hashing method. But, when you see them in your database, are the passwords stored properly, with the $a$## prepending the password? Also, try directly copying one of those passwords out of your datatable and plugging it in to password_verify, to see that it's not getting corrupted somehow, on retrieval. I'm thinking it would have to be corrupted before insert, or after select in some way.

Comment: @EvadeCaptcha Added the password method and how it is stored in the database.

Comment: Try to directly plug that value into the password_verify function, along with the password you know to be correct, and see if that is true or false.

Comment: Also try to echo $password and $info['password'] (somewhere safe of course), and make sure both values are actually there by the time you make it to password_verify().

Comment: @EvadeCaptcha Ah, when I echo `$info['password']` I am returned with nothing so it must not be retrieving it from the database and storing it correctly. Any ideas on what could be wrong with the `getUser` method?

Comment: It's tough for me, because I don't use that system, for sql queries. Try to echo mysqli_error($connection). Is it getting the other user information from that query? If not, there is probably something with your query. Try assigning your query to a variable and echoing that variable, instead of using it on the insert, to make sure your query is being built properly to select the user, in the getUser function

Comment: @EvadeCaptcha Well originally I was using real_escape_string, and I'm switching over. The query does work as I utilise that method with other methods in the class, however it seems to just be when I'm trying to store the records and return them at the end of te method that it doesn't seem to like. It isn't fetching and storing them correctly.